# Why don't we feel shock when there is lightning?

Tags: electricity, lightning

When there is lightning in the sky and I am are standing on the ground having no insulating material between me and the ground, why do I not feel an electric shock? If this looks stupid to you I am sorry. But can you please help me understand that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "lightning in the sky"? Do you mean lightning from cloud to cloud?

Comment: @Steeven You know that a huge amount of electricity is generated during lightening and it is transferred to the groung the next moment.

Comment: If it IS transferred to the ground, then surely it might pass through the body of a person standing there. So saying that the person will NOT be hit, doesn't make much sense unless it's for a specific situation

Comment: @Steeven There must be some electric potential created there.

Comment: Where? Your question says that it won't happen. And that is wrong. It CAN happen! Exactly because the potential is getting larger in the clouds so the charges want to move to the earth at lower potential - and they might take the easiest path, which could be through a tree, a person etc. It is not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: This electricity isn't always transferred to the ground but if that's the case and you happen standing there it will not just shock you, it will probably kill you!

Comment: Unless lightning strikes close to you, you will feel nothing since no charge has come near you.

Comment: Isn't air b/w you and lightning insulating.

Comment: Some people [do feel it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_injuries)

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Yes, air is a good insulator. That is exactly why current doesn't flow through air unless enormous amounts of charge and thus enormous potential is build up, which requires an extraordinary effect like a huge thunderstorm. It simply requires large amounts of energy to pass such a large band gap that insulators have, before becoming conducting because electrons are ripped off (excited). If this energy is supplied, air will become conducting, and this is called "dielectric breakdown" of the insulator

Comment: @Steeven Yes I know its $3*10^8 V/m$ . I was just answering question. Well thanks, it may help.

Answer (score 6):

The electric current from the sky to the ground will be dissipated over a very large area very quickly, and it does not result in either a change in the electric field in your vicinity, or in a current flowing through your body (which would be the result of an electric field change...)

The only time you will feel an electric shock is if (part of) the current from the lightning flows through you: for example, if the lightning hits your head and passes through your body on its way to the ground.

[image]

It is conceivable that there would be a tiny potential difference across the feet of the person standing on the ground - but the fraction of current flowing across the surface at a distance of more than a few meters will be extremely small.

If you consider the earth to be an isotropic conductor (of course the presence of ground water makes that an extremely poor assumption) then you can calculate the current per unit area as a function of distance from the strike point from conservation of charge. At a distance $r$, the total area of a hemisphere is $2\pi r^2$, so the current flowing near the surface will decrease with the inverse square of the distance. The median peak current in lightning is about 30 kA (see figure 6 in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3272343_Distribution_of_lightning_peak_stroke_currents_in_Ontario_using_an_LLP_system)). At a distance of 50 meters, this current is spread over about 15000 m$^2$, so you would have 2 A per square meter. Assuming your feet are 30 cm long, and connect to the top 1 cm of the soil, then you are potentially a conductor for 0.003 x 2 A = 15 mA. But of course, only a fraction of that current would actually flow through your body, as the current would distribute in accordance with the resistance of the soil and your body...

According to [this site](http://www.highvoltageconnection.com/articles/ElectricShockQuestions.htm), the threshold of perception of current in men is 5 mA.

This suggests that you would have to stand awfully close to a big lightning strike, with bare feet buried in the sand, to have even a small chance of feeling a shock. And if you are that close, I think that there are other effects (like deafening sound) that are likely to distract you from feeling a tingle...

Incidentally, the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_injuries) suggested by [Maxim Umansky](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/17215/maxim-umansky) does describe the above, calling it "ground strike injury":

> Ground strike near the person causing a difference of potential in the ground itself (due to resistance to current in the Earth), amounting to several thousand volts per foot, depending upon the composition of the earth that makes up the ground at that location (sand being a fair insulator and wet, salty and spongy earth being more conductive).